# Scala: Select following sibling in xml

Tags: xml, scala

Is there any way to select following sibling element in xml using Scala?

So if I have xml like this:

`<root>
  <childA>A</childA>
  <randomElementName>B</randomElementName>
</root>`

I would like to do selection like this:

`(root \ "childA") followingSibling text`

that will give me `"B"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's not as elegant as you expected, but it works:

```
root.
  child.
  dropWhile{ _.label != "childA" }.
  collect{ case e: xml.Elem => e }.
  drop(1).
  headOption.
  map{ _.text }
// Option[String] = Some(B)
```

There is no `XPath` in `scala.xml`, so you should work with it as with collection.